# How to prevent Windows Phone 8 from syncing contacts

Tags: microsoft-account

I have noticed that without a Microsoft account, I can't download free apps from the store.

How can I use a Microsoft account only for the store, without it syncing anything else (contacts, etc) with the cloud?

Comment: @Karan Can you, or someone with the privilege migrate it

Comment: I don't think it's possible since that site's still in beta, but I'll let a mod confirm.

Comment: Use that account only for the store, use another account for your emails. But you can't save contacts to the phone, they will be in the cloud someplace, be it Microsoft, Google, Yahoo, etc.

Answer (score 5):

To stop the phone from syncing, this is what I've figured out:

1. Go to People App
2. Open settings from the bottom bar
3. Scroll to the bottom and select your account
4. Scroll to the bottom and change `Server` to `127.0.0.1`
5. Save the changes

Caveat:
It is important to note that this may break other functionality that uses the account such as 'Find my Phone' and the ability to store purchased apps online (or at least proof of purchase)

Answer (score 0):

You're the same person I answered to yesterday, right? I'm sorry that I was wrong.

It's frustrating that I don't have a Windows Phone 8 device to check, but I think you'll be able to find such an option where you choose how often data is synced.

For people who want to go easy on their data connection, there's an option like this on every smartphone. Or if there isn't one in Windows Phone 8, it's a huge thing they've forgotten there.

For example, for email, you'd have:

When to sync mail:

- As it arrives
- Every 5 minutes
- Every 30 minutes
- Every hour
- Every day
- Manually/Never

There should be the same kind of option for contacts.

You should be able to set it so it's "synced" with your Microsoft account, but you have to say when it's synced. Then it'd be synced once (and if you really don't want the info on their servers, you can just delete it from Outlook.com or such after the first and last sync), and then you're in control, and decide when to ask it to sync. And then you just don't ask it to sync, ever. And now your contacts should be on your phone only forever waiting to be synced.

Comment: I can't find this option in the settings for any of the applications or the phone itself, so it would help to know exactly what to change.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'm doing the best I can. But I don't have a Windows Phone 8 device. :/ Maybe it can help if I show you where the option is in desktop Windows 8? :x

Comment: Maybe, however, I have Windows 8 desktop, and its interface is fairly dissimilar.

Comment: Ah. Then you probably already know where the options are. I guess we'll just have to hope someone with a phone like yours (I wish I had one to be honest) comes by. Or you can always ask Microsoft. No promises though, because they often reply silly things.

Comment: I've just found an option that seems to be the one you talk about in the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't have the Manulally option.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed the email server to a local loopback, and it stopped syncing.

Comment: Lol. That was nasty. Poor phone, being owned like that. ~ But it's weird that it didn't have an option to "never"/"manually" sync. They're just forcing people to waste their precious mobile Internet megabytes. >_> If for some reason your new solution doesn't work at some point, I just thought of something: if you don't use mobile Internet (3G/4G/whatever), perhaps there's an option to "sync only on mobile networks". I think I saw that in the Hotmail app for Android a while back. I found it silly, because "who'd not want to use wi-fi when available?", but if there's that, it might be for you.

Comment: Unfortunately 4G is the way to go for me ^^

Answer (score 0):

Steps to take.

1. Get into your phone settings
2. select Email+account
3. Select Microsoft account
4. Scroll down to "server" and input 127.0.0.1
5. select the tick and return to start screen.
6. Hit people tile and go to settings(the three dots bottom right corner)
7. select "filter my contact list" then ensure the checkbox is selected for Hotmail or whatever microsoft account is listed.

Accept the changes and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank You!!
I've only had a windows phone for a few days and this was driving me insane, to the point of returning the phone. As suggested, changing the Hotmail server address to 127.0.0.1 did the trick. Also, Select filtering to allow contacts from Hotmail now displays my contacts in phone AND no longer syncs with the Hotmail server. I've downloaded free apps with no issues. Did i say thank you? :)